# Apple Product Sales

Tags: data-request, products

Is there somewhere I can get in csv format for the last five years of Apple sales, split by product, globally per week? I'm interested in units.

Comment: The best time resolution will be quarterly, as part of their quarterly financial filings. And [this site](https://barefigur.es/companies/apple/retail/) says "Apple stopped reporting separate Retail figures since Q4/14."